# HTML drag and drop - Receive an event when an draggable element is NOT dropped on an valid drop-agent

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

How could i receive an event when an draggable element is NOT dropped on an valid drop-agent. The listener for drop and dragend are asigned in different closures. I would prefer to not rely on timeouts and global namespaces.

I have a workaround that uses timeouts and global namespaces that shows the functionality that I am looking for.

```
//global namespace

let justDropped = false;



(() => {
  //closure for the drag events
  let dragElement = document.querySelector("#drag");

  dragElement.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
    if (!justDropped) {
      console.log("Not dropped on an valid drop-agent");
    }
  })
})();


(() => {
  //closure for drop event
  let dropElement = document.querySelector("#drop");

  dropElement.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    justDropped = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      justDropped = false;
    }, 10)
  })
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the drop target on drag functions, but you could add a global drop function where you can check the target and do the checking if it's outside the target.

```
(() => {
  const htmlElement = document.querySelector("html");
  const dropElement = document.querySelector("#drop");

  htmlElement.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    if (e.currentTarget !== dropElement) {
      console.log("Not dropped on an valid drop-agent");
    }  
  })
})();
```